# Deshabilitar boton dependiendo de su estado

Tags: javascript, html5

Solicito de su ayuda llevo poco desarrollando en **ASP.NET MVC** y estoy que cargando unos datos en una tabla con la ayuda de **Javascript**, solicito de ayuda para lo siguiente, necesito deshabilitar el botón de **Asignar** dependiendo de su estado, si su estado es **TERMINADO** el botón debe aparecer como la siguiente imagen de forma `disabled`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente lo tengo de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es el código html con el cual construyo mi tabla

**Index.cshtml**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Lista</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="ticketsTable" class="table table-hover dt-responsive flex-nowrap" style="width: 100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Número</th>
                            <th>Solicitante</th>
                            <th>Asunto</th>
                            <th>Categoría</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Asignar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>    
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este es el código con el cual cargo cada una de las columnas con **javascript**

**Lista.js**

```
"columns": [

            {
                "title": "Número", "data": "TicketFolio", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData) {
                    $(nTd).html(`<a href=${document.getElementById("ticketDetail").value}?ticketNumber=${oData.TicketId}&ticketFolio=${oData.TicketFolio}>${oData.TicketFolio}</a>`);
            }, "searchable": true }, 
            { "title": "Solicitante", "data": "TicketAplicant", "searchable": true }, 
            { "title": "Asunto", "data": "TicketSubjet", "searchable": true },            
            { "title": "Categoria", "data": "TicketService", "searchable": true }, 
            { "title": "Estado", "data": "TicketStatus", "searchable": true },          
            { "title": "Asignar", "data": null, "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData) {
                $(nTd).html(`<button id=${oData.TicketId} class="btn btn-primary">Asignar</button>`);
            }, "searchable": false, "orderable": false }
        ]
```

El estado **TERMINADO** se almacena en la columna **Estado**

**UPDATE:**

La estructura que tendría **Estado** y para saber si es **TERMINADO** lo hago a través de mi formulario de registro en un combo asignando su respectivo estado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como recorro la lista para asignar

```
var data = query.Select(ticket => new 
                {
                    ticket.TicketId,
                    ticket.TicketFolio,
                    ticket.TicketAplicant,
                    ticket.TicketService,
                    ticket.TicketStatus,
                    ticket.TicketSubjet,
                    ticket.TicketEmployee
                }).ToList();

                var ticketList = new List<object>();

                foreach (var ticketIter in data)
                {
                    var queryRecords = TicketDetailsModel.ConsultRecordList(db, ticketIter.TicketId);
                    var dataRecords = queryRecords.OrderBy(records => records.RecordId).ToList();

                    ticketList.Add(new
                    {
                        ticketIter.TicketId,
                        ticketIter.TicketFolio,
                        ticketIter.TicketAplicant,
                        ticketIter.TicketService,
                        ticketIter.TicketStatus,
                        ticketIter.TicketSubjet,
                        ticketIter.TicketEmployee
                    });
                }

                return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, ticketList, filteredCount, totalCount));
```

El atributo `TicketStatus` corresponde al estado

Comment: como seria la estructura que tendría **ESTADO** ??, mejor dicho como sabes si es terminado ? , si  `"searchable"` si esto es **`true`** tiene que habilitarse el botón o viceversa ?

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO revisa nuevamente la pregunta acabo de realizar la aclaración a tu inquietud

Comment: a ver si entiendo , cuando cargas la tabla por cada iteracion debes validar el estado para poder mostrar si se puede asignar o no bloqueando el boton ?, Cuando te decia la estructura me referia a la estructura del `json` o del dato en si, con que variable en esa `lista.js` validarías si esta terminado ?

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO exactamente, pero solo dependiendo de su estado recuerda si es **TERMINADO** se debe deshabilitar el botón de **Asignar**

Comment: Por eso en ese caso tienes que hacer una validacion y agregar una propiedad **`disabled`** a tu botón, muéstrame como recores la lista para asignarla

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO Revisa nuevamente la pregunta agregue el fragmento de código que me pedías

Comment: @Sebatian-salazar ahora si.... dejame reviso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98381/discussion-between-francisco-j-blanco-and-sebastian-salazar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

según lo que hablamos,

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente, en tu código **LISTA.JS** debes agregar una validación para saber si el estado es **TERMINADO** y así crear el botón.

```
"columns": [

            {
                "title": "Número", "data": "TicketFolio", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData) {
                    $(nTd).html(`<a href=${document.getElementById("ticketDetail").value}?ticketNumber=${oData.TicketId}&ticketFolio=${oData.TicketFolio}>${oData.TicketFolio}</a>`);
            }, "searchable": true }, 
            { "title": "Solicitante", "data": "TicketAplicant", "searchable": true }, 
            { "title": "Asunto", "data": "TicketSubjet", "searchable": true },            
            { "title": "Categoria", "data": "TicketService", "searchable": true }, 
            { "title": "Estado", "data": "TicketStatus", "searchable": true },          
            {
            "title": "Asignar", "data": "TicketStatus", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData) {
                if (sData == 'TERMINADO' || sData == 'CERRADO') {
                    $(nTd).html(`<button id=${oData.TicketId} class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Asignar</button>`);
                } else if (sData != 'TERMINADO' || sData == 'CERRADO') {
                    $(nTd).html(`<button id=${oData.TicketId} class="btn btn-primary">Asignar</button>`);
                }
            }, "searchable": true, "orderable": false
        },
```

y tenias un error al data de **Asginar** lo estabas cargando **`null`** tienes que cambiarlo por `"data": "TicketStatus"`